# What's the threshold for creating data URI in css?

Tags: page-speed, background-image, data-uri

I'm interested in benchmarking, or best practices.

I have 10 icons on my website. 
They are all `background:url(…) no-repeat;`.
Assuming sprites are not the answer (for any god given reason) **how big** or **how small** a file would you place directly in data URI, and which one would you allow to be downloaded?

I want the page to be extremely fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data URI limit is set by the browser that is viewing your site.

- Internet Explorer 6 and 7 does not support Data URI.
- Internet Explorer 8 has a Data URIs limit of 32KB
- Internet Explorer 9 has no Data URI limit.

**PNG Sprites are better than Data URI**

Personally PNG sprites are the way forward because with PNG sprites the Caching is far Superior since you can set the expire weeks ahead awhile a CSS caching should be much lower if you intend to add to it on a daily, to weekly basis. Furthermore iPhones and iPads will not cache files when they are X Big.

- The iPad caches files up to 25.6KB. (first ipad)
- The iPhone 3GS caches files up to 51.199KB.
- The iPhone 4 caches files up to 102.3KB.

**It's not all about lowering the requests (Though it is a major one)**

So while lower requests do help the page load speed its also good to know the limitations and the actual speed of all devices - since web page speed tests do not test every environment and device.